# for_each that gives two (or n) adjacent elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, foreach

Is there a standard implementation of a `for_each` that does call with the element and the next one in the range?

For example take the range `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, I would like to call a function `f` with each element and its successor: `{f(0, 1), f(1, 2), f(2, 3), f(3, 4), f(4, 5)}`
Note how the last element is left out because it has no successor.

It would also be nice if there was a generalization of this to n successors that get passed with the element itself.

Up to now I have always solved this in terms of a handwritten loop with iterators.
However, I would like to go much more along the lines of C++11 range based for or `std::for_each` to avoid boiler plate code.

### Examples

```
// today: handwritten loop
for(Range::iterator current = range.begin(); current != range.end(); ++current) 
   f(*current, *std::next(current));

// near future: wrapped version
for_each_pair(range.begin(), range.end(), f);

// slightly further future: generalized version
for_each_tuple<n>(range.begin(), range.end(), f);
```

### Additional Question

The name of the function could be improved. To me `for_each_pair`/`tuple` sounds like all subsets of size n of the range should be returned (which is in itself another problem I would like to solve). So I'd like some suggestions on better names like:

```
for_each_adjacent<n>
```

## Temporary Solution

I have posted [my own solution](https://github.com/NobodyOnSE/adjacent_element_iterator) over at [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84996/adjacentelementsiteratoradaptor-for-random-access-iterators). I won't duplicate it here because this is about a standard solution and there are already enough roll-your-own answers.

Comment: A quick perusal of the [`<algorithms>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) of C++ show no evidence of such a beast, but it wouldn't be the first time I've missed something. Any particular reason you continue to write boilerplate code rather than just templatize an iterator based solution and throw it in your toolbox ?

Comment: @WhozCraig: So far only the nagging feeling that there must be a standard implementation (std or boost) and pure laziness have held me from wrapping up my own version.

Comment: Ah, well I can't comment on boost, as I never use it (was bitten severely on a commercial product that relied on their serialization algorithm, which changed; banned for life from work). It certainly appears you have the faculties to do this, and have even considered extensions (the tuple approach as a general solution is a good one). You may have to dust off an afternoon and jam it out. +1 for the interesting question, btw.

Comment: Just as a quick heads up: I posted some code relating to this on [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84996/adjacentelementsiteratoradaptor-for-random-access-iterators). When it is more polished I might post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 5):

You could actually abuse `std::unique` or `std::adjacent_find` for this: the predicate is called with each consecutive pair in the iterator range, and as long as the predicate always returns false, it won't modify anything or return early.

Disregarding that particular hack, I would implement this as an iterator adapter, not an algorithm. That is, I'd implement a `consecutive_tuple_iterator<N>` which would return all tuples of N consecutive items. Then you could use it for things like `count_if` and `includes`, not just `for_each`. (It wouldn't be appropriate for most modifying algorithms, though.)

Comment: Although it would probably work, the hack would rely on implementation internals of the two mentioned algorithms which is not a good idea. You are right about the iterator, I had not yet encountered other uses but this is mainly due to the fact that I had the boilerplate for_each up to now.

Comment: It would not rely on implementation details in the case of `adjacent_find`; the behavior of that algorithm is closely defined by the standard.

Comment: I would go with a skip forward iterator adaptor for a first pass.  Then modify it to return a tuple, and tweak `end` detection.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest thing would be to write it as a generic algorithm, then apply it many times.

```
 template< typename FwdIter, typename Func >
 Func for_each_pair( FwdIter iterStart, FwdIter iterEnd, Func func )
 {
     if( iterStart == iterEnd )
        return func;

     FwdIter iterNext = iterStart;
     ++iterNext;

     for( ; iterNext != iterEnd; ++iterStart, ++iterNext )
     {
          func( *iterStart, *iterNext );
     }
     return func;
}
```

As I was asked why it returns func (rather than void), this is typical of a for_each because of the fact that

1. func could be an object
2. It is passed by value.

func may "accumulate" some kind of state, but it is the copy we have made into this algorithm that is accumulating it, not the user's original object. We therefore pass them back the modified "func" object.

Comment: Why do you return `func`?

Comment: Because func doesn't have to be an actual function but can be an object, which can hold state, and these will often be copied. The func object passed in has been copied so will not receive the new state, so we return it back, with any modifications

Comment: In such a case I think would be better to write an `std::accumulate`-alike function, it's more expressive. If the function status (its result type) is complex, just provide operators as required and you're good to go.

Comment: The alternative is to make a special iterator then apply it to any algorithm. You'll create it with a make_pair_iter_begin and make_pair_iter_end for the collection and possibly one for a random forward iterator.

Answer (score 5):

With C++ 11 and the new iterator helper functions [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and [std::prev](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) for iterators, the second variant of the standard algorithm [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) can be used to iterate over adjacent elements.

Here is an example that generates a list of adjacent pairs from a list:

```
std::vector<int> nums{3, 4, 2, 9, 15, 267};
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> num_pairs;
if (!nums.empty()) {
    std::transform(
        std::begin(nums), std::prev(std::end(nums)),
        std::next(std::begin(nums)),
        std::back_inserter(num_pairs),
        std::make_pair<
            decltype(nums)::const_reference,
            decltype(nums)::const_reference
        >
    );
}
```

Comment: This would also be possible in C++03 with just a bit more code. However, it only solves the problem for two neighboring nodes and does more than a simple for each (one could work around that by providing a dummy iterator).

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you want, but take a look at [cpplinq](http://cpplinq.codeplex.com/).

```
int numbers[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto pairs = cpplinq::from_array(numbers) 
          >> cpplinq::pairwise() 
          >> cpplinq::to_vector(); // yields (0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)

for(auto p : pairs)
    f(p.first, p.second);
```

Comment: I have no experience with cpplinq (which makes it "non standard" for me) but it seems that this creates a temporary vector containing the elements which is a big overhead.

Answer (score 2):

look out for C++23 views::slide(n)

```
vector<int> ints = {1, 2, 3, 4};
auto rg2 = ints | views::slide(2);
/*
{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}
*/
auto rg3 = ints | views::slide(3);
/*
{{1, 2, 3},{2, 3, 4}}
*/
```

Comment: Or even better: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/adjacent_view
also known as std::ranges::views::pairwise when N = 2.