# C++ algorithm for applying a function to consecutive elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl

Is there a simpler way to write this, e.g. by using an STL or boost algorithm?

```
std::vector<int> v { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; // any generic STL container
std::vector<int> result;
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end() - 1, // (0, 1, 2)
               v.begin() + 1,          // (1, 2, 3)
               std::back_inserter(result),
               [](int a, int b){ return a + b; }); // any binary function
// result == { 1, 3, 5 }
```

Comment: @erip Iterators and reverse iterators are not compatible types. `v.end()-1` and `v.rbegin()` point to the same element, but can't be compared.

Comment: @interjay Whoops. :)

Comment: Seems an unanswered discussion has already been brought up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927563/for-each-that-gives-two-or-n-adjacent-elements

Also, I'm sure I've seen a blog post with an implementation, I'll post it as an answer if I can find it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [binary version of `std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) can be used.

The `std::adjacent_find`/`std::adjacent_difference` algorithms can be abused.

Comment: The difference to my algorithm is that `adjacent_difference` copies the first element to the output sequence unmodified. This is actually quite stupid because it introduces the need to have compatible input and output types. :/

Answer (score 10):

I propose using a for loop:

```
for(std::vector::size_type i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++)
    result.push_back(v[i] + v[i+1])
```

---

A more generic loop for bidirectional iterators:

```
// let begin and end be iterators to corresponding position
// let out be an output iterator
// let fun be a binary function
for (auto it = begin, end_it = std::prev(end); it != end_it; ++it)
   *out++ = fun(*it, *std::next(it));
```

---

We can go a bit further and write a loop for forward iterators:

```
if(begin != end) {
    for (auto curr = begin,
         nxt = std::next(begin); nxt != end; ++curr, ++nxt) {
        *out++ = fun(*curr, *nxt);
    }
}
```

---

Finally, and algorithm for input iterators. However, this one requires that the value type is copyable.

```
if(begin != end) {
    auto left = *begin;
    for (auto it = std::next(begin); it != end; ++it) {
        auto right = *it;
        *out++ = fun(left, right);
        left = right;
    }
}
```

Comment: @FelixDombek I added a loop for non-random-access iterators (not as pretty anymore).

Comment: `v.end() - 1` would also require random access, so you should use `std::prev` instead.

Comment: @interjay right you are. Although, that still won't work with forward iterators :(

Comment: I missed this fact (need for std::prev) myself. +1.

Comment: Your third code snippet fails when the container is empty. (advances past `end`)

Comment: @MarshallClow thanks for the code review. I think that the simplest solution is to simply check that first.

Comment: This whole thing demonstrates the need for working, tested, out-of-the-box algorithms – self-made for loops are simply too error-prone.

Comment: For the sake of accurate documentation, the "loop for any iterator" only works with forward iterators or better, not for mere input iterators.

Answer (score 1):

I would write your own algorithm to apply a functor to each pair of elements in the container.

(Shameless blurb) In my ACCU presentation this year, "[STL Algorithms – How to Use Them and How to Write Your Own](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nXLxMYXgWs&list=PL9hrFapz4dsM1B9bI8VmEE4JJlR0m-dvo&index=10)", showed how to write one like this. I called it `adjacent_pair` (about 25:00 into the video)

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename Func>
void adjacent_pair(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Func f)
{
    if (first != last)
    {
        ForwardIterator trailer = first;
        ++first;
        for (; first != last; ++first, ++trailer)
            f(*trailer, *first);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you'd really like to write my own algorithm, I won't stop you :o)

Answer (score 1):

`std::adjacent_difference` is for exactly this, but as you mentioned, it copies the first element to the result, which you don't want.
Using Boost.Iterator, it's pretty easy to make a back_inserter which throws away the first element.

```
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>

template <class Container>
auto mybackinsrtr(Container& cont) {
    // Throw away the first element
    return boost::make_function_output_iterator(
            [&cont](auto i) -> void { 
              static bool first = true;
              if (first)
                first = false;
              else
                cont.push_back(i);
            });
}
```

Then you can `#include <boost/range/numeric.hpp>` and do this:

```
std::vector<int> v { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; // any generic STL container
std::vector<int> result;
boost::adjacent_difference(v, mybackinsrtr(result), std::plus<>{}); // any binary function
```

[See it on ideone](http://ideone.com/PpZld6)

---

When you want your binary function to return a different type (such as a string), the above solution won't work because, even though the insertion `cont.push_back(i)` is never *called* for the first copied element, it still must be *compiled* and it won't go.

So, you can instead make a back_inserter that ignores any elements of a different type than go in the container. This will ignore the first, copied, element, and accept the rest.

```
template <class Container>
struct ignore_insert {
    // Ignore any insertions that don't match container's type
    Container& cont;
    ignore_insert(Container& c) : cont(c) {}
    void operator() (typename Container::value_type i) {
        cont.push_back(i);
    }
    template <typename T>
    void operator() (T) {}
};

template <class Container>
auto ignoreinsrtr(Container& cont) {
    return boost::make_function_output_iterator(ignore_insert<Container>{cont});
}
```

Then you can use it similarly.

```
std::vector<int> v { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; // any generic STL container
std::vector<std::string> result;
boost::adjacent_difference(v, ignoreinsrtr(result), [](int a, int b){ return std::to_string(a+b); });
```

[On ideone](http://ideone.com/sn3ELy)

Comment: Nice, but still doesn't work for a functor which would change the type of the iterator (`[](int a, int b){std::to_string(a+b);}`) however this functionality could just be put into the output iterator, eliminating the need for any functor here and you could just use `std::copy`.

Comment: @FelixDombek: I'm not sure why that's not working. You can deal with that particular case [like I did here](http://ideone.com/OOaDKP), replacing the lambda back inserter with a struct that ignores `int`s and inserts `string`s.

Comment: It doesn't work with `adjacent_difference` because it copies the first element to the result range instead of applying the functor. So – because the result iterator needs to be able to accept an element of the source type – the functor cannot have any incompatible return type either.

Comment: @FelixDombek: It doesn't check though, at least in libstdc++. It just assigns the result of the argment `binary_op` to the output iterator: `*++__result = __binary_op(__tmp, __value);` That's why it works with the example I linked in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Stephan T. Lavavej has written a nice `adjacent_iterator` class here:

[How do I loop over consecutive pairs in an STL container using range-based loop syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826893/how-do-i-loop-over-consecutive-pairs-in-an-stl-container-using-range-based-loop/14829088#14829088)

This could also be used here.